# Apache 2.2 to 2.4 too many redirects

Tags: apache, tomcat, https

I have an old server which uses httpd 2.2 and this configuration works fine redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS.
Moving to CentOS and upgrading to httpd 2.4 the existing configuration causes a too many redirects to occur.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    ... SSL Setup ...

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using tomcat which is listening on port 8009 internally, I'm not sure why is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTED

The `ProxyPassReverse` directive doesn't work well with `ajp`.

1. Switch to `HTTP/HTTPS`
2. Remove the `ProxyPassReverse` directive
3. Validate you have set `RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Host`, `X-Forwarded-Port` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` appropriately as well